# How to set the location of Figure of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some `Figure` objects of `matplotlib` (may be 6), and I want to show them at the same time. However, once I used `plt.show()`, they appeared at the same location in the screen(the center of the screen).

I want those Figures do not appear at the same place, it's better to arrange them like a 2*3 matrix. I don't want to solve this problem by showing the graphs in a figure which includes 6 `axes`.

How should I do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, but with the way your OS handles multiple windows being opened by the same program. Just drag them across your screen until they fit.

Comment: There are ways to manipulate the position of a window opened from within matplotlib. Those will depend on the backend in use and possibly the operating system. Since I guess this is not the first time this question is asked, could you tell in how far other answers do not help.